# expanding a independent set to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I doubt that I misunderstand this part:

please clarify me:

if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and we have an independent set like $S$ then we can expand $S$ to a basis for the vector space easily.

if $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space and we have an independent set $S$ then again we can expand $S$ to a basis for the vector space but this time the procedure is more complicated and for proving this we must use Zorn's lemma

are this two statements correct?

Comment: yes the are correct

Comment: It's quite correct. As a consequence, every vector space has  a basis.

Comment: How would you use Zorn's lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mathnoob Let $\mathcal{P}=\{L\supset S|L\text{ is linearly independent}\}$.This is nonempty since $S\in \mathcal{P}$. Then $(\mathcal{P},\subset)$ is a poset with set inclusion. Use zorn's lemma on this to get a maximal linearly independent set $B$ containing $S$. Then $B$ is an extension of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

In case the vector space $V$ is finite dimensional it has a finite spanning set say $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. The independent set $S$ is going to have cardinality atmost $n$(see Steinitz exchange theorem). Now keep adding vectors from $X$ to $S$ which are not there in the span of the vectors already there. For instance if $x_1$ is there in span($S$) ignore otherwise adjoin to get $S\cup\{x_1\}$. Now if $x_2$ is there in span($S\cup\{x_1\}$) or span($S$)(by whatever happened in previous step) then ignore otherwise adjoin to get $S\cup\{x_1,x_2\}$ or $S\cup\{x_2\}$. Continue like this for $n$ steps to get a linearly independent set (since none of the vectors are in the span of the previous ones) containing $S$.